# How to use Google libphonenumber in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, libphonenumber

I want to use Google libphonenumber in my angular project using Typescript. I have searched a lot on the internet and found a lot of stuff but could not find anything that could serve my purpose.
Most of the content available shows the code in JavaScript. If I use the same code in typescript, it shows a lot of errors like `cannot find name require` or `module not found`. Please tell me how/where/what to write the code.
Also, plz tell me which package to install as there are many - libphonenumber, google-libphonenumber, angular-libphonenumber

Answer (score 16):

When dealing with CommonJS libraries, in TypeScript just like this **google-libphonenumber**, I'd like to suggest 2 ways about it **(Tested by me and works well)**.

Initially, I'd like to suggest to install from NPM just like this: `npm install --save google-libphonenumber`.

Then, here we go both ways of using it:

#### 1st Method

Just import it directly

```
import libphonenumber from 'google-libphonenumber';
class Something {
    constructor() {//Just example, you can chose any method
        const phoneUtil = libphonenumber.PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        console.log( phoneUtil.getSupportedRegions() );//It should works and give you some output
    }
}
```

#### 2nd Method

You still can make the power of Typescript typing or just use the existing one by: `npm install --save-dev @types/google-libphonenumber`.

Since you said that you using Angular, so you can declare that typing just installed at `src/tsconfig.app.json` ( I am using Angular Version 7 ). Here is an example I have made:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": [
      "google-libphonenumber"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Then you can just import it like usual, in Typescript "typings" way like follow:

```
import { PhoneNumberUtil } from 'google-libphonenumber';

class Something {
    constructor() {//Just example, you can chose any method
        const phoneUtil: PhoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        console.log( phoneUtil.getSupportedRegions() );//It should works and give you some output
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you may either go with libphonenumber or google-libphonenumber as both of this library having a good number of installs also google-libphonenumber seems to be more powerful

Comment: Thanks @SantoshSingh... do you have any idea about how to import google-libphonenumber into project and how to use it in project.

I don't know where should I write this code :
var phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

Comment: Install https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-libphonenumber and import * as modName from 'google-libphonenumber'

Answer (score 0):

Use ng2-tel-input . The only lib stable with angular 7 . ngx-tel-input has more features . 
But it has issues with ang7 .

Downloads from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tel-input/v/2.0.3)

Exemple of use :

```
  <input type="text"
ng2TelInput
[ng2TelInputOptions]="{initialCountry: 'UK'}"
(hasError)="hasError($event)"
(countryChange)="onCountryChange($event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the `@types/google-libphonenumber` package as a dev dependency without having to install the `google-libphonenumber` package too. This is achieved by using a root `index.d.ts` file with triple-slash directives and module declarations

```
/// <reference types="google-libphonenumber" />

declare module "google-libphonenumber";
```

I tend to do this with google libraries in general -- bonus: no imports required to consume these types in your codebase

- Example from a current project

```
/// <reference types="gtag.js" />
/// <reference types="google.analytics" />
/// <reference types="google.maps" />

declare module 'google.maps';
declare module 'gtag.js';
declare module 'google.analytics';
```