# Use google-libphonenumber in angular reactive forms validator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, libphonenumber, angular-validation

This is a basic use case for using this library. I need to verify the number if it is valid. I use angular [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) [custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation).
Validator is in file: `validators/phone-number.validator.ts`
First step is to get google-libphonenumber PhoneNumberUtil instance

Current state of my code is:

```js
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber');
const phoneUtilInstance = phoneUtil.PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

export function PhoneNumberValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    if (!phoneUtilInstance.isValidNumber(control.value)) {
      return { 'wrongNumber': { value: control.value } };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Usage in reactive form (file `contact.component.ts`):

```
import { PhoneNumberValidator } from '@app/validators';
...
ngOnInit(): void { ...
this.editPhoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [''],
  phone: ['', [
    Validators.minLength(3),
    PhoneNumberValidator()
  ]],
}); ...
```

This code can be build and executed, however, after launch I get:

```
ERROR TypeError: a.getCountryCodeOrDefault is not a function
at i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForNumber (VM145038 libphonenumber.js:4418)
```

**How to properly use this library in the Angular project as a validator?**

*Declaration*
This question is similar to [How to use Google libphonenumber in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49293864/how-to-use-google-libphonenumber-in-typescript) but in this case it is specifically about the Angular project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**I have found a solution currently:**

1. You need google-libphonenumber and also types for it:
   `npm install --save google-libphonenumber`
   `npm install --save-dev @types/google-libphonenumber`
2. Import `PhoneNumberUtil, PhoneNumber` into your `validator` file (full content):

```js
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { PhoneNumberUtil, PhoneNumber } from 'google-libphonenumber';

const phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

export function PhoneNumberValidator(regionCode: string = undefined): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    let validNumber = false;
    try {
      const phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(
        control.value, regionCode
      );
      validNumber = phoneNumberUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber);
    } catch (e) { }

    return validNumber ? null : { 'wrongNumber': { value: control.value } };
  }
}
```

3. Use `PhoneNumberValidator` in reactive form with your default region code (part of code):

```js
import { PhoneNumberValidator } from '@app/validators';
...
ngOnInit(): void { ...
this.editPhoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [''],
  phone: ['', [
    PhoneNumberValidator('US')
  ]],
}); ...
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in code demo -- stackblitz

Comment: This answer works really well except that it effectively acts as a "required" validator as well (which it shouldn't IMO) - it should first test the control.value is not empty and if it is empty it should return null (valid) - you can then combine it with a Validators.required validator if it also needs to be required.

Comment: Optional param can be used: PhoneNumberValidator(regionCode?: string):