# How to Validate mobile number with country code

Tags: angular, libphonenumber

I am having two inputs, one with country code options like CA, US and so on and another with mobile number. I saw in some of the source to use google-libphonenumber for validation and i find a custom validation for that in [Use google-libphonenumber in angular reactive forms validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530023/use-google-libphonenumber-in-angular-reactive-forms-validator) , using this custom validator bring me some errors in return validNumber ? null : { 'wrongNumber': { value: control.value } };

Type '{ wrongNumber: { value: any; }; } | null' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.

how to pass the country code and mobile number to validate and if invalidate show error in the html pass.

Answer (score 0):

In your function **PhoneNumberValidator**, try to change:

```
return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
```

for

```
return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
```

If it doesn't work, try this another one change, alone (or mix it):

```
export function PhoneNumberValidator(regionCode?: string): (ValidatorFn | null | undefined)): ValidatorFn {
```

Comment: how to pass a formcontrol name in the  phonevalidator(regioncode)